# Assigning values in a vector in non-sequential order

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, c++11, vector

I want to **implement a code similar to the below-mentioned one using vectors in the most efficient and easiest manner**.    How do I do it?

```
int a[1005];
for(int i=1;i<=1000;i+=5)
    a[i]=i*i;
```

When I try doing the same using vectors,compiler throws **assertion failed error..subscript out of range**...

```
vector<int> a;
for(int i=1;i<=1000;i+=5)
    a[i]=i*i;
```

So,I tried pushback function...However the index of vector could only be increased from 0 to number of calls to pushback and not in the way I want i.e 1,6,11,16

```
vector<int> a;
for(int i=1;i<=1000;i+=5)
    a.pushback(i*i);
```

Comment: `vector.resize(sizeYouWant);` *Edit* or `vector<int> a(sizeYouWant);`

Comment: `compiler throws assertion failed error` - No, this exception occurs during **runtime**.

Comment: Really looking forward to telepathic compilers. I'd do a lot less swearing if the program did what I wanted rather than what I told it to do.

Comment: First, what problem are you trying to solve (without mentioning `vector`)?  If it's to be able to use a data structure that allows you to add an item, regardless of value and without sizing issues, then the solution could be to use a `std::map<int,int>`, not `vector<int>`.  If you used a `std::map<int,int>`, your code would have worked with no changes whatsoever (except from changing from `vector<int>` to `std::map<int, int>`).

Answer (score 4):

Declare the vector with the size you want as a constructor argument:  `vector<int> a(1000);`

Answer (score 2):

My answer is going to be a little different than the others so far.

If the goal is to store numbers in a container, and not care about sizing, or care about whether the data is stored contiguously, then the solution could be to use a `std::map<int, int>`.

Example:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> a;
    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i+=5)
        a[i]=i*i;

    // output the results  
    auto it = a.begin();
    while (it != a.end())
    {
         cout << it->first << " has a value of " << it->second << endl;
         ++it;
    }
}
```

Live Example: http://ideone.com/sfgfmu

Note that there were no changes to your original code, except to change the declaration of `vector` to `map`.

Each entry in the map has a key/value pair of the `i` item as the key, and its square as the data.  Then you can use the `operator []` of the map similar to how you would use it for an array. However, there are differences, in that a map has to do a lookup, while an array is direct access, plus a map will fill in an entry if the item doesn't already exist.

As far as performance, the map has to store the items differently than an array for this to work.  Thus you more than likely will get a small degradation in speed, but not a lot (since a map finds items in logarithmic time, not linear).

So it's up to you whether to stick with a `vector` and deal with the resizing issue, or go with a `std::map` and live with convenience with a possible degradation in speed (but may not be a lot if any degradation, depending on your usage).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the *vector* how many elements to have.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a(1000); // 1000 elements

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 5)
        a[i] = i * i;
}
```

Also note *arrays* and *vectors* start from `0` not `1`. So a `1000` element *array* or *vector* counts form `0 - 999` (not `1 - 1000`).

Comment: This would still cause unexpected behaviour because `i` is incrementing by 5. So the array size would actually be 5001 if you started from index 1. Also int would probably have to be replaced by float because of overflow.

Comment: @fsacer I start incrementing from `0` not `1`.  And the `for()` body can only execute when `i < 1000` so its safe. Also many computers have 32bit ints these days and if that's not enough it would be more appropriate to move to a larger `int` rather than a floating point type.

Comment: @fsacer: i is limited by the test `i < 1000`; it can't grow beyond that. And anyway 5001 will definitely fit in an int, because ints must be able to hold integers up 32767 as a minimum.

Comment: I missed the condition.  Yeah long int would actually be more appropriate.